# swift - Initialising a float property to the UITextField input

Tags: xcode, swift, properties, uitextfield

I am trying to initialise a property of type float from the textfield that user keys in, in the UITextField.

I get an error of UITextField is not convertible to 'float' for the below code.

**Code of type float variable and textfield**

```
    var forceVar : Float = 0.0
    @IBOutlet weak var forceEntered: UITextField!
```

**Initialise property from UITextField**

```
forceVar = forceEntered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to cast your text to NSString and then extract the floatValue:

```
forceVar = (forceEntered.text as NSString).floatValue
```